# Cannot obtain result from searching csv file in Python

Tags: python, database, csv, search, multiple-columns

For an assignment I've got to code a program which can search a tab delimited text file of academic papers for certain values i.e. search for the author in the author column and then print the whole row. Here is the code so far...

```
import csv
import sys

#Assign File to "SearchFile"
SearchFile=raw_input(str("Enter the name of the file you want to search: "))

#open csv
reader = csv.reader(open(SearchFile, "rb"), delimiter="\t")

#Search Request
search_request = raw_input(str("Search on author (A=)or journal/conference (J=), [Q = quit]: "))

#Author Search
if search_request.startswith("A="):
    for row in reader:
        if search_request in row[0]:
            print row
        else:
            print("Sorry, could not be found")
```

I've seen some similar examples on stackoverflow, but still can't solve my problem. I can get it to read through the file but can't seem to retrieve any of the search results? I'm new to Python so if anyone could help it would be great!

Some lines of the csv file:

```
AUTHOR(S)    YEAR    TITLE    JOURNAL/CONFERENCE
Accot;Zhai  2001    Scale effects in steering law tasks Proc. ACM CHI
Acredolo    1977    Developmental Changes in the Ability to Coordinate Perspectives of a Large-Scale Space  Developmental Psychology
```

Comment: Can you post us one line of the .txt you are searching through? :)

Comment: Have you tried printing `search_request` before checking if it `startswith()` "A=" ?    You might find it isn't what you think it is.   Another thing to protect youself against that is to have an else clause for the if `startswith("A=")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one of the reasons why this doesn't work is because you've forgotten that search_request has got "A=" in it.   It's clear that this isn't what you mean: you want to search the `row[0]` for the characters *after* "A=".  So you need to strip "A=" off search_request first...

```
if search_request.starts_with("A="):
    seach_request = search_request[2:]  # strip off the selector "A="
    for row in reader:
        if search_request in row[0]:
            print row
        else:
            print("Sorry, could not be found")
else:
  print("Ooops, your selection (%s) is not supported right now" % search_result[:2])
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! With your other comment, what do you mean about the else clause? Not sure where to put it so it doesn't state "Sorry, could not be found" for every row which doesn't match, and only when there are no matches?

Comment: I updated the answer with something along the lines of what I was thinking of.   Basically, the idea is to always check the "corner cases", don't just assume anything.   Your code will be more robust and easier to debug, because it will tell you when stuff is going wrong much more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I think row[0]  does not have a "A="-prefix. You should probably cut of the prefix from your search_request string.

```
...
#Author Search 
if search_request.startswith("A="): 
    for row in reader: 
        if search_request[2:] in row[0]:
            print row
        else: 
            print("Sorry, could not be found")
```